# Find the index of numerically closest value

Tags: matlab, function, find, closest

Say I have 2 matrices in matlab :

```
A = [1 4 6 9 11 13 15 18 21]

B = [2 10 19]
```

Is there a function I can use so that, for every element in B, I am able to find the index of the closest value to that element in A. For instance, in the above example: 2,10 and 19 are numerically closest to 1,9 and 18 in A, and the indices of 1, 9 and 18 are 1,4 and 8, so the function should return [1 4 8].

I know I can use loops to do this but matlab doesn't really like loops plus my matrices are too big and iterating through all values would be very expensive on time.

Comment: Currently, I reduce the time cost by sorting the two matrices and then looking for values in a way so that the index of last closest found value in A is saved and then the search for the closest value for next element in B starts at this saved value instead of 1. everytime.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the post. It was useful :)

Comment: @vsx06 `knnsearch` is the obvious answer.

Comment: @Parag: `knnsearch` is available since which MATLAB release?

Comment: @fpe how to check that? I use R2011b and its there.

Comment: @Parag `knnsearch` is in the statistics toolbox

Comment: @Dan Yes, I know that but how to check in which version of MATLAB it was introduced?

Comment: @Parag I don't know but my point is that the fact that it's in the toolbox explains why fpe or others might not have access to it.

Answer (score 4):

I would proceed as follows:

```
% clc,clear all,close all
A = [1 4 6 9 11 13 15 18 21];
B = [2 10 19];
C = abs(bsxfun(@minus,A',B));
[~,idx] = min(C(:,1:size(C,2)))
```

Comment: Please do not add `clc,clear all,close all`. I might want to retain in cache all the executed functions for performance and keep my figures open.

Comment: Why not the shorter `[~, idx] = min(abs(A'-B))`?