# Vectorize finding closest value in an array for each element in another array

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, vectorization, cython

### Input

`known_array` : numpy array; consisting of scalar values only; `shape: (m, 1)`

`test_array` : numpy array; consisting of scalar values only; `shape: (n, 1)`

### Output

`indices` : numpy array; `shape: (n, 1)`; For each value in `test_array` finds the index of the closest value in `known_array`

`residual` : numpy array; `shape: (n, 1)`; For each value in `test_array` finds the difference from the closest value in `known_array`

### Example

```
In [17]: known_array = np.array([random.randint(-30,30) for i in range(5)])

In [18]: known_array
Out[18]: array([-24, -18, -13, -30,  29])

In [19]: test_array = np.array([random.randint(-10,10) for i in range(10)])

In [20]: test_array
Out[20]: array([-6,  4, -6,  4,  8, -4,  8, -6,  2,  8])
```

### Sample Implementation (Not fully vectorized)

```
def find_nearest(known_array, value):
    idx = (np.abs(known_array - value)).argmin()
    diff = known_array[idx] - value
    return [idx, -diff]

In [22]: indices = np.zeros(len(test_array))

In [23]: residual = np.zeros(len(test_array))

In [24]: for i in range(len(test_array)):
   ....:     [indices[i], residual[i]] =  find_nearest(known_array, test_array[i])
   ....:     

In [25]: indices
Out[25]: array([ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.])

In [26]: residual
Out[26]: array([  7.,  17.,   7.,  17.,  21.,   9.,  21.,   7.,  15.,  21.])
```

What is the best way to speed up this task? Cython is an option, but, I would always prefer to be able to remove the `for` loop and let the code remain are pure NumPy.

---

**NB**: Following Stack Overflow questions were consulted

1. [Python/Numpy - Quickly Find the Index in an Array Closest to Some Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065697/python-numpy-quickly-find-the-index-in-an-array-closest-to-some-value)
2. [Find the index of numerically closest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046933/find-the-index-of-numerically-closest-value)
3. [Find nearest value in numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2566412/find-nearest-value-in-numpy-array)
4. [Finding the nearest value and return the index of array in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914491/finding-the-nearest-value-and-return-the-index-of-array-in-python)
5. [finding nearest items across two lists/arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363419/finding-nearest-items-across-two-lists-arrays-in-python)

---

### Updates

I did some small benchmarks for comparing the non-vectorized and vectorized solution (accepted answer).

```
In [48]: [indices1, residual1] = find_nearest_vectorized(known_array, test_array)

In [53]: [indices2, residual2] = find_nearest_non_vectorized(known_array, test_array)

In [54]: indices1==indices2
Out[54]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],   dtype=bool)

In [55]: residual1==residual2
Out[55]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [56]: %timeit [indices2, residual2] = find_nearest_non_vectorized(known_array, test_array)
10000 loops, best of 3: 173 µs per loop

In [57]: %timeit [indices1, residual1] = find_nearest_vectorized(known_array, test_array)
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.8 µs per loop
```

About a **10-fold** speedup!

### Clarification

`known_array` is not sorted.

I ran the benchmarks as given in the answer by @cyborg below.

**Case 1**: If `known_array` were sorted

```
known_array = np.arange(0,1000)
test_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10000)
print('Speedups:')
base_time = time_f('base')
for func_name in ['diffs', 'searchsorted1', 'searchsorted2']:
    print func_name + ' is x%.1f faster than base.' % (base_time / time_f(func_name))
    assert np.allclose(base(known_array, test_array), eval(func_name+'(known_array, test_array)'))
```

---

```
Speedups:
diffs is x0.4 faster than base.
searchsorted1 is x81.3 faster than base.
searchsorted2 is x107.6 faster than base.
```

Firstly, for large arrays `diffs` method is actually slower, it also eats up a lot of RAM and my system hanged when I ran it on actual data.

**Case 2** : When `known_array` is not sorted; which represents actual scenario

```
known_array = np.random.randint(0,100,100)
test_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
```

---

```
Speedups:
diffs is x8.9 faster than base.
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-3170078c217a> in <module>()
      5 for func_name in ['diffs', 'searchsorted1', 'searchsorted2']:
      6     print func_name + ' is x%.1f faster than base.' % (base_time /  time_f(func_name))
----> 7     assert np.allclose(base(known_array, test_array),  eval(func_name+'(known_array, test_array)'))

AssertionError: 


searchsorted1 is x14.8 faster than base.
```

I must also comment that the approach should also be memory efficient. Otherwise my 8 GB of RAM is not sufficient. In the base case, it is easily sufficient.

Comment: It does not matter if your data is sorted; the method posted by HYRY takes care of that scenario, and has linear rather than the quadratic memory performance of the diff method; his answer should be marked as the correct one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, you can compute all the differences in on go with:

```
differences = (test_array.reshape(1,-1) - known_array.reshape(-1,1))
```

And use `argmin` and fancy indexing along with `np.diagonal` to get desired indices and differences:

```
indices = np.abs(differences).argmin(axis=0)
residual = np.diagonal(differences[indices,])
```

So for

```
>>> known_array = np.array([-24, -18, -13, -30,  29])
>>> test_array = np.array([-6,  4, -6,  4,  8, -4,  8, -6,  2,  8])
```

One get

```
>>> indices
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
>>> residual
array([ 7, 17,  7, 17, 21,  9, 21,  7, 15, 21])
```

Comment: The solution works! I am just doing some small benchmarks to compare the performance. Would be great if you can highlight how you thought about vectorizing this task. That would be of more help!

Comment: Added the benchmarks in the Update section of the question. It may also be helpful to discuss the memory requirements by the two versions.

Answer (score 7):

If the array is large, you should use `searchsorted`:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
known_array = np.random.rand(1000)
test_array = np.random.rand(400)

%%time
differences = (test_array.reshape(1,-1) - known_array.reshape(-1,1))
indices = np.abs(differences).argmin(axis=0)
residual = np.diagonal(differences[indices,])
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 11 ms, sys: 15 ms, total: 26 ms
Wall time: 26.4 ms
```

`searchsorted` version:

```
%%time

index_sorted = np.argsort(known_array)
known_array_sorted = known_array[index_sorted]

idx1 = np.searchsorted(known_array_sorted, test_array)
idx2 = np.clip(idx1 - 1, 0, len(known_array_sorted)-1)

diff1 = known_array_sorted[idx1] - test_array
diff2 = test_array - known_array_sorted[idx2]

indices2 = index_sorted[np.where(diff1 <= diff2, idx1, idx2)]
residual2 = test_array - known_array[indices]
```

output:

```
CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
Wall time: 311 µs
```

We can check that the results is the same:

```
assert np.all(residual == residual2)
assert np.all(indices == indices2)
```

Comment: I don't quiet get the same results from both the methods

Comment: I have added a Clarification section towards the end of the question to explain this

Comment: The search sorted algorithm works well for me but it fails if any value of `test_array` is larger than the max value of `known_array`. In this case, `np.searchsorted` will return an index which is 1 too large to be used as an index into `known_array_sorted`.  I have edited the answer above to fix this case.  Please check it works for you!

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: use `numpy.searchsorted()`.

```
import inspect
from timeit import timeit
import numpy as np

known_array = np.arange(-10, 10)
test_array = np.random.randint(-10, 10, 1000)
number = 1000

def base(known_array, test_array):
    def find_nearest(known_array, value):
        idx = (np.abs(known_array - value)).argmin()
        return idx
    indices = np.zeros_like(test_array, dtype=known_array.dtype)
    for i in range(len(test_array)):
        indices[i] =  find_nearest(known_array, test_array[i])
    return indices

def diffs(known_array, test_array):
    differences = (test_array.reshape(1,-1) - known_array.reshape(-1,1))
    indices = np.abs(differences).argmin(axis=0)
    return indices

def searchsorted1(known_array, test_array):
    index_sorted = np.argsort(known_array)
    known_array_sorted = known_array[index_sorted]
    idx1 = np.searchsorted(known_array_sorted, test_array)
    idx1[idx1 == len(known_array)] = len(known_array)-1
    idx2 = np.clip(idx1 - 1, 0, len(known_array_sorted)-1)
    diff1 = known_array_sorted[idx1] - test_array
    diff2 = test_array - known_array_sorted[idx2]
    indices2 = index_sorted[np.where(diff1 <= diff2, idx1, idx2)]
    return indices2

def searchsorted2(known_array, test_array):
    index_sorted = np.argsort(known_array)
    known_array_sorted = known_array[index_sorted]
    known_array_middles = known_array_sorted[1:] - np.diff(known_array_sorted.astype('f'))/2
    idx1 = np.searchsorted(known_array_middles, test_array)
    indices = index_sorted[idx1]
    return indices

def time_f(func_name):
    return timeit(func_name+"(known_array, test_array)",
        'from __main__ import known_array, test_array, ' + func_name, number=number)

print('Speedups:')
base_time = time_f('base')
for func_name in ['diffs', 'searchsorted1', 'searchsorted2']:
    print func_name + ' is x%.1f faster than base.' % (base_time / time_f(func_name))
```

Output:

```
Speedups:
diffs is x29.9 faster than base.
searchsorted1 is x37.4 faster than base.
searchsorted2 is x64.3 faster than base.
```

Comment: May you please give a sample code which conforms to the test data I have provided?

Comment: The assertion fails when `known_array` is not sorted; eg.          known_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, 100)
test_array = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000)

Comment: I have added a Clarification section to the end of the question to illustrate the same

Comment: Both searchsorted1 and searchsorted2 fail

Comment: I removed the assert because it's not defined which value of known_array should be picked if more than one is the closest.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest I could come up  with. This requires the **array** to be sorted.
The **value** could be a scalar or a list/array.

```
def find_nearest(value, array):
    idx = np.searchsorted(array, value, side="left")
    cond = np.logical_and(idx>0, np.logical_or(idx == len(array), np.fabs(value - array[idx-1]) < np.fabs(value - array[idx])))
    return np.where(cond, array[idx-1], array[idx])
```