# Locate closest match index of one column and return another column values w.r.t a Test 1D Array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `Array1, Array2`. `Array1` has shape `(27000,)`, while `Array2` has shape `(501,3)`. Both of the arrays have `np.float32` numeric values inside them. I have to do the following:

1. First, for every element in `Array1`, find the (index of) closest matching element in the first column of `Array2`.
2. Next, retrieve the values for these 'nearest-matching' indexes from second (or third) column of `Array2`. Here, I would like to have a choice whether I want to have values from second or from the third column.

I am seeking a fast Numpy solution to this (preferably one-liner), because this operation appears somewhere inside my code and right now my current implementation (where I break it into two parts i.e. first get indexes, then select corresponding values) of this seems to be taking some time. My current implementation is:

```
indices   =  abs(Array1[:, None] - Array2[:,0][None, :]).argmin(axis=-1)
final_val =  Array2[indices,2]
```

One might expect that a simple Numpy operation for this should be fast enough, however, I need to run my program thousands of time, so any time saving on this (most time consuming part) would help me greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer here:

[NumPy: Vectorize finding closest value in an array for each element in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780017/numpy-vectorize-finding-closest-value-in-an-array-for-each-element-in-another-a)

In short, use `numpy.searchsorted()` for better performance.